# Publishing more than actual messages in Google Pub/Sub using Node.js and csv-parse

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-pubsub, node-csv-parse

Using Node.js, Google Pub/Sub, csv-parse.

Use case  - 
I have a large csv file to process and import in my DB. It has few third party APIs which take 1 second to process each row. So process flow is below -

1. User uploads the file
2. node server upload the file in storage and send message to PubSubNo.1
3. Now My listener listens to above pubsub and starts processing these messages , it download the file and start breaking each row and publishes to another PubSub for further processing
4. In the end I parallel process these smaller row messages and achieve faster processing.

Problem - 
As soon as my listener downloads the file it send x no. of row messages to next PubSubNo2 but when i check its subscription it shows more than x messages.
e.g. I upload a 6000 record csv and on subscriber it shows more than 40K-50K messages.

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/pubsub": "1.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "csv-parse": "^4.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "google-gax": "1.14.1",
    "googleapis": "47.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pg": "^7.18.1",
    "winston": "^3.0.0"
  }
```

Publisher Code

```
async processFile(filename) {
    let cnt = 0;
    let index = null;
    let rowCounter = 0;
    const handler = (resolve, reject) => {
      const parser = CsvParser({
          delimiter: ',',
        })
        .on('readable', () => {
          let row;
          let hello = 0;
          let busy = false;
          this.meta.totalRows = (parser.info.records - 1);
          while (row = parser.read()) {
            if (cnt++ === 0) {
              index = row;
              continue;
            }
            let messageObject = {
              customFieldsMap: this.customFieldsMap,
              importAttributes: this.jc.attrs,
              importColumnData: row,
              rowCount: cnt,
              importColumnList: index,
              authToken: this.token
            }
            let topicPublishResult = PubSubPublish.publishToTopic(process.env.IMPORT_CSV_ROW_PUBLISHING_TOPIC, messageObject);
            topicPublishResult.then((response) => {
              rowCounter += 1;
              const messageInfo = "Row " + rowCounter + " published" +
                " | MessageId = " + response +
                " | importId = " + this.data.importId +
                " | fileId = " + this.data.fileId +
                " | orgId = " + this.data.orgId;
              console.info(messageInfo);
            })
          }
        })
        .on('end', () => {
          console.log("File consumed!");
          resolve(this.setStatus("queued"))
        })
        .on('error', reject);
      fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(parser);
    };
    await new Promise(handler);
  }
```

And Publish module code

```
const {
  PubSub
} = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');

const pubsub = new PubSub({
  projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID
});
module.exports = {
  publishToTopic: function(topicName, data) {
    return pubsub.topic(topicName, {
      batching: {
        maxMessages: 500,
        maxMilliseconds: 5000,
      }
    }).publish(Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data)));
  },
};
```

This works without any issues for file os 10, 100,200,2000 records but giving trouble with more as in for 6K records.
After I publish 6K records there is an error of UnhandledPromiseRejection for all 6K records e.g.

```
(node:49994) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Retry total timeout exceeded before any response was received
    at repeat (/Users/tarungupta/office/import-processor/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/retries.js:65:31)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/tarungupta/office/import-processor/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/retries.js:100:25)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)
(node:49994) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 6000)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that your publisher is getting overwhelmed when you have 6,000 messages to publish. The reason is that you create a new instance of the publisher for each message that you create in your `publishToTopic` method. Consequently, you are not getting to take advantage of any batching and you are waiting 5 seconds to send every message. That's a lot of overhead for each message. It could mean that callbacks are not getting processed in a timely fashion, resulting in timeouts and attempts to resend. You want to create your `pubsub.topic` object a single time and then reuse it across publish calls.

Comment: Awesome. Worked for me, another problem with copied code. I was using same code to publish to another Pub/sub but it was quite sparsely timed thus no issues. I tried with 20K records and it was super smooth. I still don't understand the technicality of it working. Could you please elaborate a little bit?
PS: I tried it without `maxMilliseconds` option.

Comment: When you say you don't understand the technicality of it working, what do you mean exactly? Why reusing the topic worked when creating it each time didn't? Why creating separate instances prevents batching from working?

Comment: Technicality as you mentioned it is getting overwhelmed for publisher so was my bad code making 6000 different publisher and was firing all 6K of them at a time and then timing out for response back from GCP. So yes why reusing worked? and also why GCP couldn't response back to 6000 new topic object even if firing individually.

Comment: The topic object is quite heavyweight. Creating 6,000 resulted in a backlog of callbacks to run in your client. This means results from the service couldn't be processed quickly, so the client retried the publishes thinking they timed out, which built up even more work in your client.

With only one copy of the topic object, messages are batched and there are fewer requests to the server, meaning your client has less work to do. The issue isn't GCP, it can handle millions of messages a second. Your client can't handle all of the async work that has to run if you use 6,000 instances of topic.